# Exponential-like decay function

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function, curves

I want to create a curve with a non-linear decay. It should cross the points `y(x=0)=1` and `y(x=100)=0.1`.
What I tried is using a function of the following shape:

`y = a^(-bx)`

One example would be `y = 5^(-0.0143x)`

However, no matter which values for `a` and `b` I choose, as long as the line crosses the two points mentioned, it always looks the same. For example `y = 50^(-0.0059x)` or `y = 0.5^(0.0332x)` create exactly the same curve. However, I want a function where I can vary the parameters to influence the "convate-tivity" of the decay. In the picture added, I want to be able to not only get the solid line, but also the dotted lines. Is there a (simple) function which can to that?

[image: Curves]

Comment: Note that the parametric form of your function has two free parameters, but you are imposing two constraints, which means that there are no degrees of freedom beyond what can satisfy the constraints. That's why your solutions don't just look exactly the same, but are exactly the same -- $50^{-0.0059x} = (0.5^{log(50)/log(0.5)})^{-0.0059x} = 0.5^{log(50)/log(0.5)*0.0059x} = 0.5^{0.0333x}$. A good take-away is that you'll want to propose a parametric form with at least *three* parameters a, b, and c, and then impose the constraints at the values 0 and 1 of x.

Comment: Try the form $y = e^{-ax^b}$.